# how to assign column name in a dataframe . If that column already has values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am calculating the value counts of usa state in a data frame . I have obtained a data frame . I have assigned a column name to the value counts i.e 'Class_0' , but how to assign column name i.e state_usa to the 1st column of data frame i.e columns of the state.

```
df1 = data[data['project_is_approved']==0] 
['school_state'].value_counts().rename('Class_0')
df1.head()

Actual-Output-Obtained
CA    2183
TX    1382
FL    1041
NY    1027
NC     738
Name: Class_0, dtype: int64

Output-wanted
State    Class_0
CA       2183
TX       1382
FL       1041
NY       1027
NC        738
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df1 = data[data['project_is_approved']==0] 
['school_state'].value_counts().rename('Class_0').reset_index('State')
```

Answer (score 0):

From pandas docs you should use [pandas.DataFrame.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to 'Alter axes labels', i.e. rename a column in a dataframe.

Hope this helps!